# Signout from google play Game service Leaderboard screen

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-signin

When the leader board is shown in the screen there is a option called "setting". Inside that there is a option "Signout". When I clicked signout the leaderboard is closed,

### Issue.

If I checked the sign in status the the below function always returns true. Means that the mGoogleApiClient is connected. and hence when I tried to click the icon which shows the leaderboard it always has the responseCode RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED.

This issue goes away if i restart my App

```
public boolean isSignedIn() {
    return mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected();
}
```

### Question.

How do the program knows that the user has signed-out in the leaderboard screen.

Comment: What kind of `RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED` returned? Can you use that to check the status of your app sign out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to catch the signout in `onActivityResult` and call `GoogleApiClient.disconnect()` yourself since the connection is in an inconsistent state ([source](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesActivityResultCodes#RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED)).

So, when you open the leaderboard using the following code:

```
activity.startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(googleApiClient, leaderboardId), MY_CUSTOM_LEADERBOARD_RESULT_CODE);
```

You should handle the signout event as follows:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    boolean userLoggedOut = (responseCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED) && (requestCode == MY_CUSTOM_LEADERBOARD_RESULT_CODE);
    if (userLoggedOut) {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should handle the [RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesActivityResultCodes#RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED) by calling [reconnect()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#reconnect()).

If there was a transient error with the connection, this will silently reconnect the player.  If they did actually signout, onConnectionFailed() will be called, and you can reset the UI/game to be appropriate for the not logged in state.

```
   if (resultCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED) {
       mGoogleApiClient.reconnect();

   }
```